# vba get weekday name from a files created date?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the weekday name, i.e. Friday, of a file created date.

Here's my code:

Weekday = WeekdayName(Weekday(objFile.DateCreated))

This doesn't work.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

THanks

Comment: Does not work in what way?

Comment: Works fine for me. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Have you created a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library? Did you instantiate your FSO object? Your question would be greatly enhanced if you shared all the relevant code. Also your generic statement that it doesn't work provides no detail as to the nature of the error. Can you please provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
Sub test()
MsgBox WeekdayName(Weekday(FileDateTime("C:\Users\Documents\test.xlsm"), vbUseSystemDayOfWeek))
End Sub
```